# Can't create reasonML project on Windows

Tags: windows, npm, reason, bucklescript, bsb

I just started learning reasonML and I want to create my first project. I installed  `bs-platform` globally with `npm install -g bs-platform`. I want to create the first project with the command `bsb -init my-new-project -theme basic-reason` but PowerShell is displaying this error message:

```
bsb: The term "bsb" is not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, script file, or program
executable. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path exists, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
To the line character: 1: 1
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bsb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Is there another way to install `bs-platform`?

Comment: Sounds like `npm` isn't configured correctly. I don't use Windows, so I can't provide much in the way of specifics, but I would think you need to put `npm`s `bin` folder in your path.

Comment: Thanks glennsl! I reinstalled nodejs and the command worked.